# Expected argument of type "UserBundle\Entity\User", "NULL" given

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

I would like edit my Clan, when i set the Co Leader to null, comes the error, but the rest it work.

> "Expected argument of type "UserBundle\Entity\User", "NULL" given"

I hope someone can help me.

Clan.php

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="coLeader", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 * })
 *
 *
 */
private $coleader = null;
```

//Solution by @SamDufel (After $coleader append "= null")

```
/**
 * Set coleader
 *
 * @param User $coleader
 * @return Clan
 */
public function setColeader(User $coleader = null) // <--
{
    $this->coleader = $coleader;

    return $this;
}
```

ClanType.php

```
->add('coleader', null, array(
      'label' => 'clan.coleader',
      'required' => false,
      'empty_data' => null,
      'placeholder' => 'form.nobody',
));
```

ClanController.php

```
 /**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Clan entity.
 *
 * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="clan_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Clan $clan)
{

    $current_leader = $clan->getLeader();
    $current_coleader = $clan->getColeader();

    $editForm = $this->createForm('ClanBundle\Form\ClanType', $clan);

    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User');
        $current_leader =  $user->find($current_leader);
        $current_coleader = $current_coleader != '' ? $user->find($current_coleader) : '';

        $leader = $editForm['leader']->getData();
        $coleader = $editForm['coleader']->getData();

        if($leader != $current_leader ){
            $current_leader->removeRole('ROLE_LEADER');
            $user_leader = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($leader);
            $user_leader->addRole('ROLE_LEADER');
            $user_leader->setClanId($clan);
        }

        if(!empty($coleader) || $coleader != $current_coleader){
            $current_coleader ? $current_coleader->removeRole('ROLE_COLEADER') : '';
            $user_co = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($coleader);
            $user_co->addRole('ROLE_COLEADER');
            $user_co->setClanId($clan);
        }

        if(empty($coleader)){
            $current_coleader ? $current_coleader->removeRole('ROLE_COLEADER') : '';
        }

        $em->persist($clan);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('clan_edit', array('id' => $clan->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render(
        'ClanBundle:clan:form.html.twig',
        array(
            'clan' => $clan,
            'form' => $editForm->createView(),
            'status' => 'edit'
        )
    );
}
```

User.php is Default from FOSUserBundle,except 3 entities in my User.php

```
//...

class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Clan", mappedBy="leader")
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Clan", mappedBy="coLeader")
 */
protected $id;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->roles = array('ROLE_USER');
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ClanBundle\Entity\Clan")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $clanId;

//...
```

Comment: Can you post the setter for $clan->coleader?

Comment: @SamDufel
I've added it under //Edit

Comment: Try changing `public function setColeader(User $coleader)` to `public function setColeader(User $coleader = null)`

I suspect the form component is trying to set a null value where none is allowed, causing the error you're seeing.

Comment: @SamDufel Perfectly it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

there is modern way:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/php7/nullable-types

you can use '?' before type of argument:

```
public function setFunFact(?string $funFact): void
{
}
```